# How to loop through all non empty rows using apache poi?

Tags: java, loops, nullpointerexception, apache-poi

I want to loop through all rows until I encounter `null`

```
int startRow = 4;

ArrayList<String> uniques = new ArrayList<String>();

int k = 0 ;
while (sheet.getRow(startRow+k).getCell(2) != null) {  // null pointer here ?
    uniques.add(sheet.getRow(startRow+k).getCell(2).toString());
    k++ ;
}
```

I get a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: getRow(startRow+k) return null.. or sheet is null.

Comment: Are you sure sheet has been initialized properly, and that it has a row at startRow+k?

Comment: I checked with console , the sheet is ok . I have updated my code above

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are checking the `Cell` if it's `null`, but not the `Row` itself.

```
while (sheet.getRow(startRow+k) != null &&
       sheet.getRow(startRow+k).getCell(2) != null) {
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It works . But i still do not understand . When I `System.out.println(sheet.getRow(startRow+k).getCell(2) != null)` I get `true` . So , it must be sufficient to check only for the cell to be not null ?

Comment: You may get `true` for one iteration, but another iteration brings the next value of `k`, and the next `Row` might not exist.